# OpenVZ Can't initialize containers after install

Tags: virtualization, openvz, centos6, containers

I have installed OpenVZ on centos 6 on a dedicated server.
I followed quick installation guide on openvz wiki.
After installing thru yum, I don't know why, but grub.conf wasn't automatically
updated to accomodate new kernel, so I had to do it manually.

I edited grub.conf, added openvz kernel and rebooted - it went fine.
Server went up into openvz kernel and it worked, it started openvz service byitself.

But after I created a container, added IP to it and attempted to start it, I couldn't.

Here is the output from the shell:

```
[root@cloud2 ~]# vzctl start 86
Starting container ...
Container is mounted
Container start failed (try to check kernel messages, e.g. "dmesg | tail")
Container is unmounted
[root@cloud2 ~]# dmesg | tail
[ 1973.401596] CT: 86: failed to start with err=-105
[ 2107.113850] Failed to initialize the ICMP6 control socket (err -105).
[ 2107.155523] CT: 86: stopped
[ 2107.155543] CT: 86: failed to start with err=-105
[ 6348.282184] Failed to initialize the ICMP6 control socket (err -105).
[ 6348.330348] CT: 86: stopped
[ 6348.330361] CT: 86: failed to start with err=-105
[45184.024002] Failed to initialize the ICMP6 control socket (err -105).
[45184.072086] CT: 86: stopped
[45184.072099] CT: 86: failed to start with err=-105
[root@cloud2 ~]#
```

I don't know what is wrong.
I tried different templates, debian 6, centos 6, i386, amd64, but the issue is the same.

What is the problem?

Comment: "Failed to initialize the ICMP6 control socket" means that it could not open an IPv6 ICMP connection.  Check your IPv6 settings (if any) and your firewall (iptables) rules.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, turns out that the problem was from this container setting:
vzctl set 54 --numothersock 120
if you remove it (or set it to something like 1200) the container starts fine.